# How to use data in a content type from another content?

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to use data in a content type from another content?

I will create a website for a football club. I want to add a content type for clubmembers (approx. 250 members) with personal information.

The members could order clothes from the club through a board member, who will keep the orders per member through a page.

To not have to re-enter some data, is it possible to establish a link with the personal member page? For example, I want to use some fields that are contained in another content type.

If it's possible, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest to use [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities.

Also you can take a look [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module.

> This project provides 'node_reference' and 'user_reference' field
>   types.